# 'Error: duplicate value found: unknown' error on page layouts with recordId

Tags: metadata-api

I'm getting this infamous error. I've read through some posts but I have'nt seen any get it from a page layout. Also most don't get an ID in their error message I do:

> layouts/Opportunity-FS Renewal Capture.layout -- Error: duplicate value found: unknown duplicates value on record with id: 0Jo4C0000003wvl

I have soql and sosl queried for the Id but found nothing. Where else can I look? If the error message contains the ID surely it exists somewhere in my org, right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object is a '[PlatformActionListItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_PlatformActionListItem.htm#apex_class_Metadata_PlatformActionListItem)'. It appears that you have a duplicate item in your metadata. You'll need to check the file closely for duplicate items. Note that this is not a sort of record you can query in the normal sense, as it is metadata.

Note that you can easily figure out the type of an ID by using this small execute anonymous script:

```
System.debug(Id.valueOf('0Jo4C0000003wvl').getSObjectType());
```

This works for almost all types of Ids. To run a script like this, go to the Developer Console in Salesforce, then Debug > Open Execute Anonymous Window.